# Imagine the shape from spinning a ring

Tags: geometry

What kind of geometric shape do I get by spinning a ring 360 degrees, with the spin axis centered on a point on the ring?
[it spins like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5pxp.jpg)

Comment: You get a hollow torus, special case of the inner radius being 0.

Comment: @WeatherVane I thought the shape would overlap onto itself and not be legit, I have a poor imagination, haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a $Torus$ with inner radius equal to zero.
[image]

Comment: Seyed. Just beautiful!

Comment: Oh wow, beautiful indeed!